# Attribute - hide/show | jQuery/java

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is releated to a game, however I'm curious about the results I get with a part of my code. At the top of my code (global) I have put

```
playerJob = "police";
```

So here's my code:

```
if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "police" && playerJob != "police") ) {
        $( this ).hide();
    } else {
        $( this ).show();
    }

    if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "mechanic" && playerJob != "mechanic") ) {
        $( this ).hide();
    } else {
        $( this ).show();
    }
```

- It works fine if I set the playerjob = "police". Then it only
  displays the button which I have (in HTML) set to
  data-require="police" - which it is supposed to do.
- If I do playerJob = "" (nothing), it hides both buttons - which it is
  supposed to do.
- If I do playerJob = "mechanic" it displays both the one that
  data-require="police" and data-require="mechanic" - which it is
  **NOT** supposed to do.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

*Why* is because if the first condition is true you don't prevent the second conditional from running which would not be true and would undo whatever was done in first conditional

Seems like you could simplify this whole thing down to:

```
$( this ).toggle( $(this).attr ("data-require") ===  playerJob );
```

---

[`toggle(boolean)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) is comparable to hide/show depending on boolean

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did try that, and it does display the menu I want to display. However, it hides all the rest of the menus (which aren't releated to the job) too.

Answer (score 0):

The last condition runs... And may override the first.

Try a `return;` after a condition is meet.

```
if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "police" && playerJob != "police") ) {
  $( this ).hide();
  return;
}

if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "mechanic" && playerJob != "mechanic") ) {
  $( this ).hide();
  return;
}

// If no conditions are meet...
$( this ).show();
```